# R error when using ggplot2 :"Discrete value supplied to continuous scale"

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

My data is about the soil environmental vairiables for two plant species. I want to make boxplots side by side for different soil layers grouped by species. It's all ok when I code for the first graph layer:

```
 p<-ggplot() + 
     geom_boxplot(data=soil,
                 aes(x = depth,y =pH,fill = Species))
```

However, when I add the second layer using:

```
 p<-ggplot() + 
     geom_boxplot(data=soil,
                 aes(x = depth,
                     y =pH,
                     fill = Species))+
     geom_boxplot(data=soil,
                  mapping = aes(x = depth,
                                y='wc(%)',
                                color=Species),
                  position='dodge')
```

an error showed up:

```
Discrete value supplied to continuous scale
```

I have searched topics about this error and changed `mydata$depth` as `numeric`, but it didn't work. Could someone help me?

My data link: [mydata](https://pan.baidu.com/s/1bpTtxvh)

Comment: You can't add a string within `aes()`. The function expects variable names or a constant. For more information on how to build boxplots, see: http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_boxplot.html

Comment: Please note that most people will not download data from external links. Please make the question reproducible _within the question itself_, thanks. What is `y='wc(%)'` supposed to represent? If it a variable within that data.frame you'll need to use backticks. Although it is usually easier to just avoid those characters in variable names and use `+ ylab("wc(%)")`. You _can_ use strings, but they will be interpreted as a single discrete value, which is why you get the error (for boxplots the y should always be numeric).

Comment: Thanks for all the advice. This problem is solved by changing `y='wc(%)'`to `mydata$'wc(%)'`, just as @Axeman suggested. I have learned to set variable names more concisely. Sorry for the post format, I'm green to this community. I'll learn the guidelines and post better later on.

Comment: That is not what I suggested! Don't use dollar notation inside aes!

Comment: @Axeman said to use backticks, i.e., `y=\`wc(%)\``. I also want to emphasize that `mydata$'wc(%)'` is totally wrong and will lead you down the wrong path, even if it seems to work in the current example.

Comment: Great,I now know I mistook `y=~wc(%)`for backticks.@Claus Wilke. What I mean in my last comment is that @Axeman show me the reason why `y='wc(%)'`is interpreted as discrete value, Sorry for my misguide. I have searched topics about _$_. It's  technically difficult for me to fully understand why, but it seems that using _$_  tends to raise potential failure risk.  Better to avoid using it this way. Thanks again.